# Spark: Spark not using the all the executors configured

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

We are running a spark streaming application it has batches queued up ..but it's not using all the executors that were configured to it ..

[image]

it's configured to use **24** executors but actually it's only using **16** and batches are getting queued up

[image: Spark UI executors]

how can we make it use all the 24 executors and not let it queue batches up

Comment: There is no other jobs running in the cluster?

Comment: nope that's the only job running

Comment: Does your cluster has 24 containers?

Answer (score 2):

> it's configured to use 24 executors but actually it's only using 16

Your job is **expecting** 24 containers/executors to be allocated to it but it is receiving only 16. This could be because of following reasons:

1. **Cluster is not configured to provide expected amount of resources**

Resources could be either memory or vcores configured by your underlying cluster manager(yarn/mesos). You can solve this by checking your cluster resources and configuring it accordingly.

2. **Cluster doesn't have enough resources throughout the lifetime of your job**

This could be because other jobs are running on the same cluster and part of cluster resource is consumed by them.